# Can I make this CLP(FD) query terminate in a shorter time?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, clpfd

I have the following CLP(FD) query:

```
?- use_module(library(clpfd)).
?- [I,N,M,J] ins -2147483648..2147483647, 
I - 3*N #= X, X in 1..2, 
I - 5*M #= Y, Y in 1..4, 
I - 15*J #= 0.
```

In SWI-Prolog already when posing the query without a label/1
goal, the interpreter practically hangs. I don't expect it
to terminate in a short time.

How can I modify the query, some reordering etc.. so
that it delivers the expected answer "false"?

Bye

P.S.: After pressing ^C and t after some while, I see that the CLP(FD)
system is still busy.

Comment: I get the expected result of 'false' in my interpreter.

Comment: you might be entering your query with newlines, copy and paste the query like this: `[I,N,M,J] ins -2147483648..2147483647, 3*N #= X, X in 1..2, I - 5*M #= Y, Y in 1..4, I - 15*J #= 0.`

Comment: Newlines are not the problem, SWI-Prolog runs with or without newlines, it is not sensitive to newlines. What termines a query in Prolog is a period (.) with a blank or newline.

Answer (score 3):

Very easy:

First, replace `I` by `J*15` ; and put the big domains last:

```
?- 15*J - 3*N #= X, X in 1..2, 
      15*J - 5*M #= Y, Y in 1..4, 
      I #= 15*J,
      [I,N,M,J] ins -2147483648..2147483647.
   false.
```

Factors as above are not always detected, and propagation as such is weak since it could easily blow up the representation of the domain.

Comment: Good job. Interesting. Investigation needed.